# What is colcon build?

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, colcon, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS2 on windows and suddenly I see the build system has changed from `ament build` to `colcon build`. Is this an update ?

In my windows machine, when I call `colcon build`, it throws an error, `the command "colcon" is either false or not found`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294532/what-is-colcon-build-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, `colcon` is the new build tool replacing `ament_tools` as of the upcoming release ROS 2 Bouncy. You can find more information about it in the [design article](http://design.ros2.org/articles/build_tool.html).

You will have to check / redo (part of) the instructions for setting up your machine which have been updated with steps to install `colcon` since you followed them.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-06-19**:
@Dirk Thomas : If possible, kindly update the instructions as well as there isnt mentioned to download the colcon dependencies and it is extremely confusing.